# Parameterisation of complex trigonometric functions

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, parametrization

I've run in to the question of parameterising a complex trig function, say sin(z), in the form (x(t),y(t)) for t over some reasonable interval, say [0,2pi].

The question specifically, and in fact only, asks for the parameterisation of the function, in that form, over that interval.

I'm tempted to say this is a simple case of

z(t)= (t,sin(t)) but I feel I'm missing something more fundamental to complex numbers.

I've got sin(z) in terms of its real and imaginary parts, eg

sin(z)=sin(x)cosh(y)+icos(x)sinh(y)

this seems like the way to go, but how would I go about putting t in there?

Comment: Can you give the question verbatim as it came to you? As written the intent is ambiguous. Are you actually trying to calculate the image of $\sin$ (or show $\sin$ is injective in some region) by parametrizing the images of horizontal and vertical lines in the $z$-plane...?

Comment: The question simply asks for the parameterisation of the graph of the sine fn, 'over the interval' 0 to 2pi, in form (x(t),y(t)). I'm a little confused myself!

Comment: "Parametrization _of the graph_" does help. Presumably your book is trying to convince you that the complicated-looking definition of $\sin z$ extends the real definition. I'd interpret the question to mean "Set $x + iy = t$", i.e., $x = t$ and $y = 0$, just as you have done.